# How to request for refund

Tags: wallet

I send funds (bitcoin) to Bitcoin Core Wallet by mistake, how can I request a refund?

https://bitcoincore.org/

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to ask whomever you sent the funds to. Once you've sent coins, they are effectively irreversibly transferred.

Comment: Bitcoin Core is not a company. If you sent funds to an address you generated using Bitcoin Core yourself, you have sent the funds to your own Bitcoin Core wallet. You can use it to send the funds elsewhere.

Comment: I sent the coins to the Address provided from the Bitcoin Core Wallet client., and they provided support to contact this community forum StackExchange.com. But here's the company sire https://bitcoincore.org/

Comment: Who told you to come here? Where? Who is "they"?

Comment: I checked and when I tried to send fund my Bitcoin core wallet telling me that I have zero (0) amount balance.

Comment: What Im trying say was, if you go to this url and click the Contact tab you'll see it there  https://bitcoincore.org/

Comment: Yes, community support is available here for technical questions about Bitcoin and the workings of Bitcoin Core. However, nobody can help you get coins back that you sent elsewhere. See my answer below; you need to contact the owner of the wallet you sent the coins to (or, if it's you who created the address, just use Bitcoin Core to send the coins back).

Comment: Is your Bitcoin Core instance fully synchronized with the network? Are you sure you created the address yourself?

Comment: Upon checking with the Bitcoin Core client page, I do see "Synchronizing with network" still going which says at the bottom "1 year and 3 weeks behind". Is that the reason why the available balance amount is zero?

Comment: Yes, the balance won't show up until the client is synchronized up to the point where the transaction was included in the blockchain. You can check with "getaddressinfo <youraddres>" in the debug console (without the ""<> characters)  whether the address is yours. If it is, and there is a transaction crediting it, it will eventually show up.